# Constructing class from variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I'm trying to create a class called `Sink` which will create a pointer to the class you pass in, this is to wrap an api in RAII.

In the full version of this code, the custom class also inherits from another class, and there is static assets to check this. The pointer is also passed to the api.

But to keep it simple I've removed this.

This is the error I get from [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/)

```
 In function 'int main()':
43:30: error: no matching function for call to 'Sink<OneArg>::Sink(int)'
43:30: note: candidate is:
10:5: note: Sink<CustomSink, Args>::Sink(Args&& ...) [with CustomSink = OneArg; Args = {}]
10:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

**Code:**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

template<typename CustomSink, typename... Args>
class Sink
{
public:
    Sink(Args&&... args)
    {        
       _ptr = std::make_unique<CustomSink>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);        
    }
    ~Sink() 
    {
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<CustomSink> _ptr;
};


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class NoArg
{
public:
    NoArg() {};
    ~NoArg() {};
};

class OneArg
{
public:
    OneArg(int a) {
        std::cout << a << '\n';
    };
    ~OneArg() {};
};
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


int main(){
    Sink<NoArg> noArgSink;   
    Sink<OneArg> oneArgSink(5);  

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue here is with the placement of the template type `Args`.  Right now you have `Args` in the class tempalte so

```
Sink<OneArg> oneArgSink(5);
```

Says `Args` is empty so `Sink`s constructor expects no arguments.  What you need to do is move `Args` to the constructor by making it a template.  That gives you

```
template<typename... Args>
Sink(Args&&... args)
{        
   _ptr = std::make_unique<CustomSink>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);        
}
```

And now the constructor will deduce the arguments passed to it instead of having to specify it when you declare the class.

Answer (score 5):

The template arguments of the constructor should be moved from the class to the  templated constructor:

```
template<typename CustomSink>
class Sink
{
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    Sink(Args&&... args)
    {        
       _ptr = std::make_unique<CustomSink>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);        
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<CustomSink> _ptr;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

According to your design, you have to write:

```
Sink<OneArg, int> oneArgSink(5);
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/253f1d69ed4cae33)

Indeed, number and type of arguments of constructor are determined by variadic part of your template (`typename ... Args`). But this part is attached to class, not to constructor. So you have to specify it when you instantiate your template.

Otherwise, if you want to respect your instantiation and let compiler determines template arguments, you have to move variadic part of your template to constructor (see [Jarod42 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43806411/3932569), or [NathanOliver's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43806448/3932569))

Answer (score 1):

The way you declared the class `Sink` means you need to specify `Args...` at template instantiation.

That means if you declare `Sink<OneArg>`, you are effectively making `Args...` empty and the constructor doesn't expect any arguments. That is why the compiler complains about passing an argument to constructor.

You only need the variadic template in the constructor. This way you can even accomodate classes having multiple constructors with different number of arguments.

```
template<typename CustomSink>
class Sink
{
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    Sink(Args&&... args)
    {
        _ptr = std::make_unique<CustomSink>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    ~Sink()
    {
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<CustomSink> _ptr;
};
```